# The Ulam matrix and the definition of measurable cardinals.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

I believe I have a pretty good handle on what an "Ulam matrix" is after reading Ulam's famous 1930 paper on the subject as well as looking at some of the previous answers to questions about that object here on MSE.  What I still don't understand, however, is how being able to set up an Ulam matrix for a Real interval, as Ulam does in his original paper, allows one to describe a measurable cardinal, which in fact he does not do in that paper.  It seems to me that all the Ulam matrix allows one to do is specify an uncountable number of pairwise disjoint subintervals on the line, but how does that in turn allow one to define a measurable cardinal, a set with a vastly higher cardinality than the set of all those subintervals.  I am obviously missing something important here.

Comment: No: If you have a Ulam matrix on a cardinal, you have a witness that the cardinal is not measurable.

Comment: Anyway, you are perhaps mixing up the notions of measurable and (atomlessly) real-valued measurable. The latter cardinals are large in one sense (weakly inaccessible and even more) but small in another (all have size at most $|\mathbb R|$).

Answer (score 5):

The Ulam matrix argument shows that if there is a $\sigma$-complete measure on the real numbers, then the real numbers are *not* of size $\aleph_1$, and more generally the measure concentrates on some $\kappa\leq2^{\aleph_0}$ which is weakly inaccessible.

I suggest Chapter 10 in Jech's Set Theory (3rd Millennium Edition) as a good introduction to the topic as a whole.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Asaf.  It is both useful and brief.  How often can one say that?!

Comment: Well, given that it took you nearly 14 months, I'm guessing that not that often. :-D

Comment: Please excuse me for not thanking you at that time the question was submitted.  I did indeed consult Jech at the time as you suggested, but I only noticed yesterday, when rereading through the answers to the question once again, that I had neglected to thank you then as well. So I decided that doing so late was still better than not doing so at all.

Comment: It's fine, don't worry about it. :)